# how string array declare global and initialize with different value

Tags: java, android, arrays, string

In my code i need to initialize array by using switch statement but when i am tried it showing error like...."Array constants can only be used in initializers" ...how to solve this..

```
public class Arrayclass {
String[] mStrings;
void setfor()
{
    int i = 0;
    switch(i)
    {
    case 0:  mStrings = {
            "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/f308a9s5ycuc3mh/1.jpg",
            "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/cmc7qe74ckr5z2u/24.jpg",
            "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/4h353n2virybjql/25.jpg",
            "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/t9gta0rpaze7j4f/26.jpg",
            "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/b9sv9nki52e7zvg/27.jpg",
            "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/gyg7kvnlnv753lf/37.jpg" };
        break;
    case 1:  mStrings = {
            "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/f308a9s5ycuc3mh/1.jpg",
            "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/cmc7qe74ckr5z2u/24.jpg",
            "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/4h353n2virybjql/25.jpg",
            "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/t9gta0rpaze7j4f/26.jpg",
            "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/b9sv9nki52e7zvg/27.jpg",
            "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/gyg7kvnlnv753lf/37.jpg" };
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Away from the declaration, you must use `new String[] {...};`.

Comment: can you explain little more...how to use...please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Away from the declaration, you must use `new String[]` on your array initializer:

```
case 0:  mStrings = new String[] {
        "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/f308a9s5ycuc3mh/1.jpg",
        "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/cmc7qe74ckr5z2u/24.jpg",
        "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/4h353n2virybjql/25.jpg",
        "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/t9gta0rpaze7j4f/26.jpg",
        "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/b9sv9nki52e7zvg/27.jpg",
        "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/gyg7kvnlnv753lf/37.jpg" };
```

According to the [JLS, Section 10.6](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.6),

> An array initializer may be specified in a declaration (§8.3, §9.3, §14.4), or as part of an array creation expression (§15.10), to create an array and provide some initial values.

The "array creation expression" refers to the [JLS, Section 15.10](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.10), which makes you prepend the array initializer with `new Type[]`.

> ArrayCreationExpression:
>       new PrimitiveType DimExprs Dimsopt
>       new ClassOrInterfaceType DimExprs Dimsopt
>       new PrimitiveType Dims ArrayInitializer 
>       new ClassOrInterfaceType Dims ArrayInitializer

Answer (score 1):

That syntax you are using is only valid if used when you declare the array variable.

Try:

```
case 0:  mStrings = new String[] {
...
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a perfect example of when to use the String resources android provides.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html

I would open your strings.xml file and define each of these options as a string array there:

```
<resources>
    <string-array name="planets_array">
        <item>Mercury</item>
        <item>Venus</item>
        <item>Earth</item>
        <item>Mars</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

Then declare your strings[] globally like so:

```
String[] vals;
```

Then in your switch do this:

```
Resources res = getResources();
vals = res.getStringArray(R.array.planets_array);
```